# Is the world of "A Song of Ice and Fire" round or flat?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

It's unclear from "A Song of Ice and Fire" (AKA Game of Thrones), at least from what I remember, if the world is flat or round. Westeros is at the west of the "known world" - but if you kept going west, what would you find? Would you end up at the other side, like in our world?

Answer (score 4):

George RR Martin confirmed in a [recent interview](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1206/) that the world of Westeros **is round**, etc albeit slightly larger than our own.

> "**Interviewer :** *Is your world round? I mean if Dany traveled far
>   enough east couldnt she come to the other side of westeros?*
>
> **GRRM :** *Yes, the world is round. Might be a little larger than ours, though. I was thinking more like Vance's Big Planet.... but
>   don't hold me to that*."

For the record, the planet in Vance's "[Big Planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Planet)" stories is described as being approximately 25,000 miles in diameter in comparison with Earth's 8000(ish) miles.

[image]

Comment: This question and answer are both needless duplicates of another. I could understand if the answer was different but its not.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock - it's been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah but I think it should be deleted because it has no new information and the other question was much better, because it had more answers and a better question. I think for future users the question should be deleted so that they get the best answer.

Comment: @Pobrecita it's for reputation I guess ;)